# EPPlus LoadFromCollection not working with passed context parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus

After days of samples, demos, tutorials, walkthroughs, etc., ...
I created the code below based on what I've learned.
It works perfect when hard coded with an entity (as shown in the top commented 2 lines for the Advertisers db table).
It creates the excel file, then it offers it up for download to the user via the browser.

However, I wanted to make it a general purpose utility for creating and downloading other entities in my db.
I've refactored this from my original method:
by replacing all the 'Advertisers' references with the passed in parameter 'listTitle'.
Then, I replaced the var adv with the passed in parameter 'context' in var ctx.

[Updated]

I plan to call this method with a collection list I create from other areas of my code (similar to the way I used the var adv, commented (i.e., context = db.Publisher.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList())),
and pass it in as the context parameter in the method call.

(ex., ExportExcelList("Publishers", context)).

Now, I get the red squigglies on the line with LoadFromCollection, and it won't build my code properly.

So my questions are:
How can I get this to work?
Is there a way of getting this to work without hugh blocks of code that include annonymous object types and GUID's (as described in other posts)?
Am I just missing a using statement?
Or should the type of the context parameter be different?

Currently, for the EPPlus using statement, I'm using: using OfficeOpenXml;
I've installed EPPlus via Nuget.

This is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportExcelList(string listTitle, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        ////create the list of advertisers [ HARD CODED HERE ]
        //var adv = db.Advertisers.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();

        var ctx = context;

        //create the path and filename to use for the excel file and check for file exists/delete here.
        //here xfile is the name of the excel file without the directory path.
        ....

        file = new FileInfo(filename);  //this is the file object used for creating the new excel file.

        //create the excel file
        using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(file))
        {
            ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(listTitle);
            var worksheet = ep.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(ctx, true);    //this line barks at the ctx usage, it wants explicit type declaration.

            ep.Save();

        }

        //download the excel file to the user
        using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(file))
        {
            //Write it back to the client
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + xfile);
            Response.BinaryWrite(ep.GetAsByteArray());
        }

        //end this process
        return null;
    }
```

I haven't found a solution that would allow me to do what I wanted.

Many thanks to @CodingYoshi for his insights.

Below is my temporary solution. For now I'm using a switch case scenario.
Not too happy about it, but it serves the purpose for now, in spite of it's limitations.

Hopefully, someone here at SO can treat to a better solution. I hope.

[ Updated Code ]

```
            //since I can't pass the context in by parameter when calling this method, I've decided to use a switch case scenario and just pass in the listTitle
            switch(listTitle)
            {
                case "Advertisers":
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(
                        db.Advertisers.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList(),
                        true);
                    break;
                case "Publishers":
                    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(
                        db.Publishers.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList(),
                        true);
                    break;
            }
            ep.Save();
```

Comment: You have to pass actual collection object as first parameters in `LoadFromCollection` not context object.

Comment: Are you saying that I can't get around hard coding the ctx variable inside the method?

Comment: What is `ApplicationDbContext`?  (I am not very strong with MVC or is it EF?).  In order to use `LoadFromCollection` it needs to implement `IEnumerable<T>` as show in the source code here:  http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase.cs

Comment: @Navoneel I was trying to reuse the code which is why I was attempting to pass in a parameter that contained an object that implemented an IEnumerable of Type ... That's where I got stuck. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Ernie ApplicationDbContext  is the name of my DbContext. Thank you for the link, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That line breaks because it is expecting IEnumerable but you are passing an ApplicationDbContext. If you want to do what you are after, you need to somehow figure out a way to enumerate all the dbsets in your ApplicationDbContext and pass them one by one to the LoadFromCollection method.

I know DbContext has a property which will allow you to do this: `GetDbSetProperties`, not sure if ApplicationDbContext has something similar. That will get you all your tables into Excel.

The next thing you will need to worry about is the filters and sort code. For example, maybe you want to sort by a specific field (by Name for advertisers as you have) or maybe you want to filter them. Normally this will be passed in using a predicate but since your are hitting the action method from the browser, that is not an option. Therefore, you can create multiple meaningful actions such as ExportAdvertisersSortedByName, ExportTopAdvertisers, ExportSomeOtherEntity etc. For these actions you will hardcode the entity like you have above and then the common code for epplus export can be in another method.

This way you can export a whole database, or specific items for specific needs.

Comment: I've updated my code with a workaround of sorts for now in my OP. I appreciate your thoughts and insights. I know there has to be a way to pass the dynamic types to make this work.

Comment: I said you can traverse all the dbset types in your context and pass those to it but there will be no filters or sorts unless you create all your entities to have some common interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection to pass the collection name dynamically.

So like this

```
var p = ctx.GetType.GetProperty(listTitle).getValue(ctx, null)
```

and see further details [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/generic-data-access-using-linq-to-sql-and-C-Sharp/).

```
public static IList<T> SelectAll<T>() where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                using (NWindDataContext context = new NWindDataContext())
                {
                    // get the table matching the type
                    // and return all of it as typed list
                    var table = context.GetTable<T>().ToList<T>();
                    return table;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```